# Numpy's broadcast in Pandas

Tags: broadcast

I want to reproduce Numpy's broadcast using pd.DataFrame but do not seem to be able to do it elegantly. If I do not use '.values' or a 'for' loop across keys, I get a wrong answer - please see screen shot. 
Any idea?
Thx.
[image]